# Table caption not showing

Tags: tables, pdftex, captions

I have the following code running in overleaf using pdfLaTeX

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{$C_2$ matrix}
\[
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
C_2 & \texttt{L1} & \texttt{L2} & \texttt{L3} & \texttt{L4} \\ \hline
\texttt{L1} & \textbf{0.6} & 0.133 & 0.133 & 0.133 \\ \hline
\texttt{L2} & 0.133 & \textbf{0.6} & 0.133 & 0.133 \\ \hline
\texttt{L3} & 0.133 & 0.133 & \textbf{0.6} & 0.133 \\ \hline
\texttt{L4} & 0.133 & 0.133 & 0.133 & \textbf{0.6} \\ \hline
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}
```

that produces the following output but without the desired caption.

[image]

How can I fix that? Thanks.

Comment: If the caption is not showing that is due to some code you have not shown. Please fix your example to be a complete small document that shows the problem, then someone will be able to debug it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: If I make your code minimally compilable by prefixing it with `\documentclass{article} \begin{document}` and affixing `\end{document}` to it, the caption shows up just fine. It's important that you provide all information needed to enable readers to replicate (and, next, diagnose and solve) the issue you say you've come across.

Comment: Please do show us the 4 or 5 lines of code in your document that precede `\begin{table}`.

Comment: BTW, \centering has no effect on either \caption or displayed math.  Both are already centered.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As it turns out the problem was due to some lines I had copy pasted in the beginning of my document that messed up image and table captions. Thanks

Comment: that's the usual thing and why all examples should be a complete document that shows the problem not a fragment that no one can test.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot reproduce your picture.
Below is what I tried at overleaf using pdflatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{$C_2$ matrix}
\[
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
C_2 & \texttt{L1} & \texttt{L2} & \texttt{L3} & \texttt{L4} \\ \hline
\texttt{L1} & \textbf{0.6} & 0.133 & 0.133 & 0.133 \\ \hline
\texttt{L2} & 0.133 & \textbf{0.6} & 0.133 & 0.133 \\ \hline
\texttt{L3} & 0.133 & 0.133 & \textbf{0.6} & 0.133 \\ \hline
\texttt{L4} & 0.133 & 0.133 & 0.133 & \textbf{0.6} \\ \hline
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As it turns out the problem was due to some lines I had copy pasted in the beginning of my document that messed up image and table captions.

Comment: @DaMike, you are welcome. Happy to know that your found the answer.